# Promise return multiple values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

I use the following code to return promise which is working **OK.**
The promise return the `data` value

```
run: () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ....

}).then((data) => {
    let loginApi = data[0]
   let test = 1; 

    }).catch((err) => {
        if (err.statusCode === 302) {
            var data = url.parse(err.response.headers.location, true)
            resolve(data )
        }
    })
});
```

I call it

```
module.run()
    .then((data) => {
```

And I was able to get the data.

now I want to return also value `test` in the resolve, how should I do it?

I try to add it like this

```
resolve({data,test});

resolve([data,test]);
```

with call like

```
module.run()
    .then({data,test}) => {
```

without success(test is empty), I read about `spread`  but this is the only option?

I use `ES6` with `bluebird` latest version

Comment: Both `resolve({data,test});` and `resolve([data,test]);` will work, what's the calling end like?..  Just a note, why are you only resolving on an error?

Comment: @Keith - like this module.run()
    .then({data,test}) => {

Comment: @Ninawatcher `.then({data,test}) => {` - you are missing an opening parenthesis here: `.then(({data,test}) => { ...`

Comment: try ->  `module.run() .then( ({data,test}) => { })`

Comment: @CodingIntrigue - thanks you are right !!!

Comment: @Keith -hanks you are right !!!

Comment: @CodingIntrigue  - add your post as answer and i'll close this question. one question :) should I use `resolve(..)`  or `return resolve(..)` or return `Promise.resolve(...)` what is recommended ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using promise chain, in promise chain you have then->then->catch->... format. Always return `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject`. `Promise.resolve` will give success result for next `then` block and `Promise.reject` will go to next catch block.

```
var module = {
  run: () => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // ....
      resolve('promise resolved')
    }).then((data) => {
      let loginApi = data[0]
      let test = 1;
      return Promise.resolve({data,test})
    }).catch((err) => {
        if (err.statusCode === 302) {
            var data = url.parse(err.response.headers.location, true)
            return Promise.resolve({data, test});
        }

        return Promise.reject(err);
    })
  }
};

module.run().then(({data, test}) => {
  console.log(data, test);
})
```